# Clang Tooling: Get file imports list for file

Tags: objective-c, clang, llvm, clang-static-analyzer

Right now I am trying to validate, that file doesn't have "violating" imports. As far as i get it preprocessor `#include` `#import` macro won't be listed listed in `ASTContext` and `SourceManager` (after all they are macro), while you certainly can track `ImportDecl` during AST traversal.

So the only option left right now to get list of imports is to get files source code and use regular expressions? Maybe there are other "proper" ways?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you can iterate on import declarations using `ASTContext` -  `local_imports`